# Create UBUNTU CD boot to a WINDOWS machine using an OS X system to create the CD

Tags: boot, usb, windows, macosx, drive

Would like to create a WINDOWS ubuntu boot-from-CD using latest OS X system. Trying to help a friend recover from an MS "registration key" and disk loss and subsequent registry trash. Any ideas?

Comment: and what have you tried? Because the instructions aren't different from doing this from Linux/Windows/Mac os. download ubuntu and unetbootin install it on a usb stick and you are off....

Answer (score 0):

Can you use a USB drive? If that's the case, I suggest you to try [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net). It works in Linux, OS X and Windows operating systems and creates bootable USB drives for a lot of Linux distributions, including Ubuntu.